# Why am I getting this pylint error: "Generator 'generator' has no 'iloc' member

Tags: python, pylint

Using Visual Studio Code, Python 3.6.7 on a conda environment, I'm getting an error message from Pylint: "Generator 'generator' has no 'iloc' member.

The code runs ok in Jupyter Notebooks. Could it be something to do with the conda environment I'm using?

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + database_filepath)

df = pd.read_sql_table('MessageClassification',con=engine)    
X = df.iloc[:,1] 
Y = df.iloc[:,4:] 
category_names=list(df.columns[4:])

return X,Y,category_names
```

Pylint underlines df with the below error message:

```
Generator 'generator' has no 'iloc' member pylint(no-member)
```

Comment: Sounds like Pylint is confusing `df` to be a generator. This issue seems to be describing something similar: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1161